# parseInt not working, get the number from the string

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the number from a string, please see my below snippet, I try "parseInt" but unfortunately not working, any help, ideas please?

```js
var tt = "test 12";

console.log(parseInt(tt));
```

Comment: Use `var num = +string.replace(/\D+/g, '');` or `var num = +string.match(/\d+/)[0] || 0;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`parseInt()` won't work since `tt` is not beginning with a number.

You can use `match()` with RegEx to extract number from a string.

```
var num = tt.match(/\d+/)[0];
```

Comment: Maybe you should also explain why parseInt doesn't work in this case?

Comment: tt is not beginning with a number.